# Pandas calculated column to accrue information

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like so  which records the type of an IP at a specific time.

```
IP   Time                 Type
101  2018-10-16 01:07:11  A
101  2018-10-16 01:08:34  A
101  2018-10-16 02:54:11  B
101  2018-10-16 14:07:39  A
```

How can I create a new column `NumSwitches` which keeps track of the number of times the type switches like so in pandas?

```
IP   Time                 Type  NumSwitches
101  2018-10-16 01:07:11  A     0
101  2018-10-16 01:08:34  A     0
101  2018-10-16 02:54:11  B     1
101  2018-10-16 14:07:39  A     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['NumSwitches'] = (df['Type'] != df['Type'].shift()).cumsum() - 1
```